# Heavy-tailed RBF kernel function

Tags: r, svm, rbf-kernel

I'm trying to run a SVM regression on some data and I want to use `ksvm` from `kernlab` or `svm` from `e1071`. But the number and type of kernels available is too restrictive. So I'm thinking of writing my own kernel function.

Let's assume I want to write the kernel for heavy-tailed RBF for which the formula is

$$
K(x_i, x_j) = \exp\left(-\gamma * ||x_i^a - x_j^a||^b\right)
$$

**How do I do this?**

I found several instances where people do something similar to the following code.

```
kp=function(xi,xj){

    diff <- xi^a - xj^a

    absValue <- abs(diff^b)

    exp(-gamma * absVal)
}

class(kp) <- "kernel"

model <- ksvm(xtrain, ytrain, type="eps-svr", kernel=kp, cross=10)
```

Is this correct or is there something else that is needed? Also how do I get the best values of `a`, `b` and $\gamma$ for my data?